# C# + GL Control blend background with form

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, opengl-es

i'm working with C# and OpenTK libraries for OpenGL, i want to blend a GLControl with the picturebox placed as background.

*** EDIT ***

i solved the problem loading source image by changing method, so now i use bitmap and bitmapdata structures:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("image.png");
BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
         ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

i'm sure that my png source has 4 channels and alpha value is 0 on black background

this is the original image:
http://imageshack.com/a/img801/517/u2z8.png

And this is the problem:
http://imageshack.com/a/img40/1729/zezj.jpg

top is the texture using GLControl and bottom is a Picturebox of Windows Form, what i'm trying to do is that black background of GLControl becomes transparent.

I put Blend cap enable and use `GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);` so i think that's not the problem.

Maybe the problem is on texture environment?

```
GL.TexEnv(TextureEnvTarget.TextureEnv, TextureEnvParameter.TextureEnvMode,GL_MODULATE);
```

Comment: You don't need to flip the pixels if you use `PixelFormat.Bgra` for the texture.

Comment: Can you please explain (screenshot?) what you mean by "But the big problem is when i try to blend the GLControl whith the picturebox, it seems like blending is done with the other information inside the picture."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to [airspace restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970688(v=vs.100).aspx), blending OpenGL and WPF *directly* may be impossible. However, it is possible to achieve the effect you are describing using an *indirect* approach:

1. Create the GLControl, but keep it invisible (i.e. don't attach it to a WindowsFormsHost)
2. Create a framebuffer object ([documentation](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/frame-buffer-objects) and [example code](https://github.com/opentk/opentk/blob/develop/Source/Examples/OpenGL/1.x/FramebufferObject.cs))
3. Render your OpenGL scene to the framebuffer object
4. Use `GL.GetTexImage2D()` to retrieve the rendered scene
5. Display the result in a regular WPF PictureBox

This way, you can use any and all WPF effects on the final PictureBox, including transparency.

(Nitpicking: it appears that you are using [OpenTK.GLControl](http://www.opentk.com), not Tao.SimpleGlControl. They share a similar function, but their APIs and capabilities are quite different.)

Comment: Yes, my bad, it is OpenTK. Thank you for your help, i will try this. I didn't know anything about that restrictions.